# How do I access a variable declared inside a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to capture the input from the user and calling it from a function. My `fetchedDate` is declared in `getInput()`. How can I make the value of `fetchedDate` globally accessible for other functions to access?

```
function getInput() {

    var fetchedDate = document.getElementById('dob').value;
    var fetchedDate = fetchedDate.split('/').reverse('').join('-');
    var fetchedDate = fetchedDate.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    getValues();
}
```

I use the value of `fetchedDate` in my `getValues()` and that is returning NaN

Comment: Can't you modify the `getValues()` function to receive the fetchedDate as an argument? Like, `getValues(fetchedDate)`.

Comment: On an additional note, do not declare the same variable 3 times in the function. Declare it once and use the variable.

Comment: No, `getValues()` itslef has some other functions and calculations in it

Comment: You can refactor the `getInput()` to `getFetchedDate()` and instead of calling the `getValues()` you return the `fetchedDate`. Therefore, you can use that function inside the `getValues()` in order to get the current `fetchedDate` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Good option:**

Turn `getInput()` into a helper function. After all, it doesn't do anything but manipulate the value of a DOM element, which is accessible any time - it doesn't need to be hooked onto your button's `onClick` event directly.

```
// returns the processed input
function getInput() {
    var fetchedDate = document.getElementById('dob').value;
    fetchedDate = fetchedDate.split('/').reverse('').join('-');
    return fetchedDate.replace(/\s+/g, '');
}

// called from button onClick
function getValues() {
    var date = getInput();
    // other code that would use `fetchedDate`
}
```

**Decent option:**

Make `getValues()` accept a parameter so that you can simply pass `fetchedDate` to it.

```
function getInput() {
    var fetchedDate = document.getElementById('dob').value;
    fetchedDate = fetchedDate.split('/').reverse('').join('-');
    fetchedDate = fetchedDate.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    getValues(fetchedDate);
}

function getValues(fetchedDate) {
    // do stuff with fetchedDate
}
```

**Okay option:**

Declare the variable in a higher scope so that you can access it from other functions freely.

```
var fetchedDate;

function getInput() {
    fetchedDate = document.getElementById('dob').value;
    fetchedDate = fetchedDate.split('/').reverse('').join('-');
    fetchedDate = fetchedDate.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    getValues();
}
```

**Poor option:**

Make the variable truly "global" by attaching it to the Window object. This is the default behavior if you don't specify a declaration with `var`.

```
function getInput() {
    fetchedDate = document.getElementById('dob').value;
    fetchedDate = fetchedDate.split('/').reverse('').join('-');
    fetchedDate = fetchedDate.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    getValues();
}
```

Comment: great explanation, for this problem I used the **Okay-option** :)

Answer (score 3):

You can declare the variable outside your function:

```js
var fetchedDate;

function getInput() {
    fetchedDate = document.getElementById('dob').value;
    fetchedDate = fetchedDate.split('/').reverse('').join('-');
    fetchedDate = fetchedDate.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    getValues();
}
```

Although it is usually not the best practice to use global variables.

Comment: This does would not work as `fetchedDate` outside the function is undefined

Comment: @RTrikha Maybe you should check what "declaration" means. Here is a simple proof of concept: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-frog-l43q1?file=/index.html

Comment: Yes, even I tried declaring the varible before using it. It works fine now, why would it not work when written this way? `var fetchedDate = document.getElementById('dob').value;` ?

Comment: @RTrikha The variable is declared in the `getInput()` function's scope, so it is only accessible in that function and not anywhere outside that function (so it would not be accessible in the `getValues()` function, unless you passed it as an argument).

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, the variable is defined in the local scope of the function and isn't accessible to the outside scope. One option is to `return` from that function to use it where you call `getInput()`.

```
function getInput() {

    var fetchedDate = document.getElementById('dob').value;
    fetchedDate = fetchedDate.split('/').reverse('').join('-');
    return fetchedDate.replace(/\s+/g, '');
}

var dob = getInput();
console.log(dob);
getValues();
```

Comment: Wouldnt solve the purpose, `getInput()` is called as `onClick` from a button